# Python image processing with image.py

Tags: python, image, processing, pixel

I'm writing a program that processes the images to be input, but I got to a point where I no longer know how to move.

the trace of the program is this:
http://pastebin.com/tqidRAfC

until now I reasoned like to write the program, but first of all the output gives me error, and then to create me the output of an image it takes 35-40 minutes.

EDIT: this is the image.py library that I used https://mega.co.nz/#!R9B1GQJC!spvwHOHNwoE_05h2ifr9lJtC72VWVzGRxlyf3hN2Zsw

```
import image

def edging( fname_in, k, fname_out ):
    img     = image.load( fname_in )             # load the image
    w, h    = len( img[0] ), len( img )          # height, width
    img_out = image.create( w, h, ( 0, 0, 0 ) )  # I create an empty image of the same dimension

    list_TUPLE = []                              # I create an empty list for tuples
    list_VAL   = []                              # I create an empty list for values

    for j in range(     h ):                     # for each value in h
        for i in range( w ):                     # for each value in w
            c0 = img[j][i]                       # c0 = tuple
            #                                    # for each value
            #                                    #     in the neighborhood of the pixel
            for J,I in [ ( j - 1, i - 1 ), \
                         ( j - 1, i ),     \
                         ( j - 1, i + 1 ), \
                         ( j,     i + 1 ), \
                         ( j + 1, i + 1 ), \
                         ( j + 1, i ),     \
                         ( j + 1, i - 1 ), \
                         ( j,     i - 1 )  \
                         ]
                if image.inside( img, I, J ):    # if that pixel I, J, is in the picture
                    c1 = img[J][I]               #    c1 = tuple
                    color_dist = cdist( c0, c1 ) #    the distance between the colors (c0, c1) given by the function cdist
                    list_TUPLE += [img[J][I]]    #    I create and update a list of tuples of neighborhoods
                    list_VAL   += [color_dist]   #    I create and update the list of values ​​calculated with the function cdist


    max          = list_VAL[0]
    max_col_dist = 0

    right_color  = 0

    for count_j in range(     h ):
        for count_i in range( w ):
            for value in list_VAL:                      # for each value in list_VAL
                if value > max:                         # if the value in question is greater than max
                    max = value                         # assigned to 'max' value
                    max_col_dist = list_VAL[value]
                    right_color  = list_TUPLE[max_col_dist]
            img_out[count_j][count_i] = right_color

    image.save( fname_out, img_out )

def cdist( c0, c1 ):
    r0, g0, b0 = c0
    r1, g1, b1 = c1
    return abs( r0 - r1 ) + abs( g0 - g1 ) + abs( b0 - b1 )
```

Comment: What is the `image` library you are using please? The only onie I know about is [this one](https://github.com/francescortiz/image), and the API is very different from the one you are using.

Comment: @user3600837 I'd prefer not to download an unknown zip object from an unknown source. Would it be possible for you to give a link to the library home page or to its doc?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not pythonic.
indexing every pixel in an image like in C/C++ will take you forever in python.

use numpy with vectorization or opencv methods, etc

Comment: [This](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661) talk has a very good note on this half way through.

Comment: Noam, if it's a homework, usually there are constraints on what you're allowed to use and what not.